# Jquery datatable - How to enable excel export on top right of table?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to enable the excel icon on data table top right and click the icon get the action class to export data.I have tried in data table, but nothing happening.please help me to enable the excel button and to get the action.

[image]

```
var oTable = $("#products1").dataTable({
       "aaData": newarray,
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bDeferRender": true,
       "bFilter": false,
       "bRetrieve": true,
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "bPaginate": true,
       "sPaginationType": "two_button",
       "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
       "bSort": true,
       "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
       "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../images/excel_export.gif",
            "aButtons": ["Excel"]
        },
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/26/)

Comment: No, its not duplicate and its not at all i'm looking. I have issue in display the icon on top right of datatable.

Comment: @ Half Crazed , can you please remove the duplicate message from my question.

Answer (score 0):

First, your jsfiddle is missing a reference to the TableTools extension for datatables, which is located here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.min.js

And if you add the reference to fix that first problem, the code complains about this line:

```
 "aButtons": [ "Excel" ]
```

Because the table tools plugin does not recognize it. You should change that to:

```
 "aButtons": [ "xls" ]
```

If you only want to allow exporting to Excel.

Here's [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/27/) updated, but notice that it won't completely work simply because the TableTools plugin uses a Flash applet to do the actual exporting. Once you put everything in your local box, should work.